# Expandable columns in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, listcollectionview

Im working on a WPF-applications to present and correct large amounts of data.
Im about to implement a datagrid containing data from 3 different sources that are populated from external services. 
To start with I will only populate the grid with data from one source, the master source.
However, sometimes an automated validator will trigger a validation warning or error on one cell and the requirement states that the user should be able to view data from the additional 2 sources in columns next to the selected one.

Something like this:

```
Standard view:

| col1 src1 | col2 src1 | col3 src1 |
|           |           |           | 
|           |faulty     |           |
|           |           |           |
```

User want to show data from source 2 and 3 next to the column  "col2 src1" like this:

```
| col1 src1 | col2 src1 | col2 src2 | col2 src3 | col3 src1 |
|           |           |           |           |           |
|           |corrected  |           |           |           |
|           |           |           |           |           |
```

and then be able to correct the faulty formatted cell with data from the other 2 soruces, and then collapse the columns again.

I am trying to use the mvvm pattern on this one so I have populated the DataGrid with a ListCollectionView so far. 
The list contains items with properties like this:

```
MyRowItem {string col1, string col2, string col3}
```

I will then have 2 additional collections with items of type like above but from 2 other sources.

I have no idea how to implement this functionality and could use some help on the logics.
What approach should I head for?

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid's columns have a property Visibility - toggle it through the binding.
Use your ViewModel to determine when you got into a state where you are ready to display the column
Whatever your ItemsSource for the grid;
Let's assume ObservableCollection, 
make MyRowItem to be more than just strings

```
public class MyRowItem
{
     string ColumnDisplayValue {get;set;}
     bool IsVisible {get;set;}
}


<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.MyRowItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding ColumnDisplayValue }" 
                Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
```

or put them in one column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock                 Width="33*" Text="{Binding crs1}" Visibility="{Binding IsSrc1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="33*" Text="{Binding crs2}" Visibility="{Binding IsSrc2Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Width="33*" Text="{Binding crs3}" Visibility="{Binding IsSrc3Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I think I got the basic idea behind your solution, I just cant figure it out all the way. Is there any way you can elaborate a little bit?
Also, it seems I cannot use <DataGridTemplateColumn Binding="{Binding....   I get an error saying "Property 'Binding' was not found in type DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: I'll add something that compiles and runs today when I have a break.

Comment: for now, I made a change to the answer, the reason binding didn't work was because I used a template col, instead of DataGRidTextColumn

Comment: No that I got to think about it, I don't know if you want to make a column visible just to expose a different source. By making the whole column visible, you are exposing the rest of the row that might not need the second source. Why not have a stackpanel inside the row, and open it up per row (by toggling it's visibility or whatever..) that way it's only the selected row that has more information if/when needed...

Comment: ok, figure that I have MyRowItem{prop FirstNameSource1, prop FirstNameSource2, prop FirstNameSource3, prop LastNameSource1, prop LastNameSource2, prop LastNameSource3} I only want to show data from Source1 first, Then be able to expand the columns for Source2 and Source3 on user command. 

Im thinking about your idea of using a stackpanel for the job. Just have to see if it suits the requirement.

Comment: i updated the answer, note that I didn't put stack panel just because, grid stretches better, but stack panel would work too. The main point here, is that the visibility for crs1 vs. crs2, or crs3 toggle will only affect that row. Which is better than adding more columns just because there is a different source on one row. Anyway, good luck